# How do you put a form inside an iframe? visual studio, html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

so, im trying to make my form to be inside an iframe, but it seems its not working, when i run the form it looks like this:

[image]

then, when i fill the fields and trigger it it looks like this:

[image]

the form now appears inside the iframe, but i wanted to be inside since the beggining, since when you load the page.

this is the code:

```
<head>
        <title></title>
<script>

    function validateForm() {
        var cel = document.forms["myForm"]["cel"].value;
        var celconf = document.forms["myForm"]["celconf"].value;
        var ocr=document.forms["myForm"]["ocr"].value;
        var ocrconf = document.forms["myForm"]["ocrconf"].value;
        if (cel==""||celconf==""||ocr==""||ocrconf=="") {
            alert("Todos los campos deben ser llenados");

        }

        else  if (cel.length != 10||celconf.length!=10) {

            alert("El numero celular debe de ser de 10 digitos");}

        else if (cel != celconf) {

            alert("Los numeros celulares ingresados no Coinciden");

        }


       else if (ocr.length<10||ocrconf.length<10) {

            alert("El OCR ingresado no tiene la longitud necesaria, ésta debe de ser de 13 o 10 digitos");

       }

       else if (ocr.length > 13 || ocrconf.length > 13) {

           alert("El OCR ingresado no tiene la longitud necesaria, ésta debe de ser de 13 o 10 digitos");
       }

       else if (ocr.length == 11 || ocr.length == 12 || ocrconf == 11 || ocrconf == 12) {

           alert("El OCR ingresado no tiene la longitud necesaria, ésta debe de ser de 13 o 10 digitos");

       }



       else if (ocr != ocrconf) {

           alert("Los OCR ingresados no Coinciden");

       }






    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<iframe name="myFrame" id="frame1">   </iframe>  
<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" target="myFrame">
<b>Celular</b><br /><input type="number" name="cel"><br />
<br /><b>Confirma tu Celular</b><br /> <input type="number" name="celconf"><br />
<br /><b>OCR</b><br /> <input type="number" name="ocr"><br />
<br /><b>Confirma tu OCR</b><br /> <input type="number" name="ocrconf"><br />
<br /><input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
    </body>



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `iframe` is empty:

```
<iframe name="myFrame" id="frame1">   </iframe>
```

The form is after the frame, so it's no surprise that the form displays after the frame.  It then posts into the frame because of the form's `target` attribute:

```
<form ... target="myFrame">
```

Since an `iframe` references a second page, you'll likely want to make two pages here.  One with just the form, the other with just the `iframe`.  Then the `iframe` can simply reference the page with the form:

```
<iframe name="myFrame" id="frame1" src="@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")"></iframe>
```

By separating the two, the form need only concern itself with being a form and posting as any form would.  And the frame need only concern itself with being a frame and referring to a page to display within the frame.  The two concerns need not know/care about each other.  Then the form doesn't need a `target` attribute, since it doesn't need to know about the frame that contains it.